# Query Help-missing record

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table as below.

For entry in col1 we should have at least one Primary and one Secondary as you can see below Both A and B have at least one Primary and one Secondary but C has only Secondary and missing primary.

I am looking for a query where i can get all rows where primary is missing a particular value in col1:

```
Col1    Col1
A       Primary    
A       Secondary
A       Secondary   
B       Primary         
B       Secondary   
C       Secondary
```

Comment: Are both columns really named `Col1`? perhaps that second column should be named `Col2`

Answer (score 1):

USE the **MINUS** operator

```
SELECT col1 from table1 where col2='SECONDARY'
MINUS
SELECT col1 from table1 where col2='PRIMARY'
```

Comment: No need for the distinct operator on your sub queries.  The minus operator will only return the distinct values not in the second query.

Comment: and fix them to  'Primary'  'Secondary'

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out Sentinel.I have now edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that's what you mean, as a start :

```
 select col1 , col2 from tablesomething where  col2 not in ('Secondary')
```

thats will give you all the records doesnt contain Secondary, in your case it will gives primary,

If you need or you want anything else please tell me.